# how to recognize image A in image B in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need a liitle Help in Windows Forms. I want to write a Code that returns true if Bitmap Image A is in Bitmap Image B. For Example : B=Screenshoot and A=little Part of Screenshot(Icon) .  Programms return True if B contains A and returns False if it isn't. Have anyone Idea how to do this.

Comment: This depends heavily on whether the version of A in B is pixel-for-pixel identical (R, G, and B values all equal) to A.  If so, you can simply search through B for a pixel identical to the top-left pixel in A and go from there if you find it.  On the other hand, if you're looking for an approximation of A in B (due to lossy compression, for example), things get much, much harder.

Comment: if(B.Contains(A)) :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with OpenCV using [feature detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) algorithms.

Note, SURF algorithm is not open source, so if this is a commercial application, you will need to license it or switch to a different algorithm (FAST/FREAK).

The [official example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html) is written in C, but here are a couple examples for [SURF](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp) and [FAST](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/FAST_feature_detector_in_CSharp) using Emgu wrapper for .Net languages.

There is also a full working [iOS example](https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial), which includes some (very badly) written code I contributed for feature detection and optical flow tracking.

Hope that helps..

-- ab1

Answer (score 0):

If the match is exact pixel to pixel, it is not difficult. One way of implementation (use memory locked bitmaps for speedup):
1) make the problem one dimensional by collapsing every column of sample bitmap into single 32bit number using hash. Calculate the hash for all relevant pixels in screenshot (hash should be rolling hash for efficient calculation).
2) use some string searching algorithm to find the sample hash substring.
3) verify the hash match by full pixel by pixel compare